# SQL Server linked server to a Microsoft Dataverse environment

Tags: sql-server, data-extraction, dataverse

I would like to connect from an on premise Microsoft SQL Server environment to a Dataverse environment in Azure. I want to be able to download data from Dataverse to SQL Server. I would like to know if i can use linked servers to do this and what are the correct properties for the connection. Thanks!

Comment: Me too.  I have connected directly using SSMS and can query the data there, but would like to connect using a linked server so I can query the data and copy it down.